# Can I run Visual Studio 2012 Unit Tests from another Assembly

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

I have created some unit tests in Visual Studio 2012 that I need to test out some API functionality. The API is used to create plugins that run within another application.

Does anyone know how I can run Unit Tests outside of the Visual Studio Environment i.e. not using the Test Explorer. The Unit Tests need to be called by a Test Plugin that is run by the main application and in the same process space.

Hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you running MSTest.
You can run tests outside VS using [MSTest.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx).

Call this exe from your plugin with appropriate command line options.